# Given a lat/long, find the nearest lat/long pair from a list of lat/long in c#

Tags: c#, geolocation

From a List of lat/long pairs, I am trying to find  nearest lat/long pair w.r.t to a given Lat/Long .  For ex- List of {42_-72,42,-75,43,-76} and a given point 42,-71

The Point 42,-72 is the nearest to 42,-71, hence output => 42,-72.

Comment: Hi there! What code do you have so far, and what trouble are you having with it?

Comment: Do you want to prioritize latitude or longitude in the case of a tie? Or do you want to return both?

Comment: It seems logical to me that you would tread them as points on a graph and calculate the distance from your target point to each candidate point, and then return the point which has the shortest distance.

Comment: What type is your `List` holding? Is it just a `List<int>` or is it an object of some kind? (Such as `List<Point>`)

Comment: It is a List of objects which in turn holds the lat/long values

Answer (score 0):

I would start by creating a method that can get the distance between two points. If we consider that in any right triangle, `a^2 + b^2 = c^2`, and the distance from point `P1` to point `P2` is `c`, then we can use this formula to get the distance between two points since we know their `X` and `Y` coordinates. The distance `a` is the difference between `P2.X` and `P1.X`, and the distance `b` is the difference between `P2.Y` and `P1.Y`:

```
private static double GetDistance(Point a, Point b)
{
    return Math.Sqrt(Math.Pow(b.X - a.X, 2) + Math.Pow(b.Y - a.Y, 2));
}
```

Then we can create a method that takes in a target point and a list of candidate points and returns the candidate which is the shortest distance from the target:

```
private static Point GetClosestPoint(Point target, List<Point> candidates)
{
    if (candidates == null) throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(candidates));
    if (!candidates.Any()) throw new ArgumentException("The candidates list is empty.");

    var minDistance = double.MaxValue;
    var closestPoint = new Point();

    foreach (var candidate in candidates)
    {
        var distance = GetDistance(target, candidate);
        if (distance > minDistance) continue;
        minDistance = distance;
        closestPoint = candidate;
    }

    return closestPoint;
}
```