# How to sort a list of lat/long by distance (in miles) from a given lat/long in C#?

Tags: c#, geolocation

I need to sort a list of lat/long values based on their distance from the user's current lat/long. I also need to display the distance in Miles for each entry.

I found [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47341040/given-a-lat-long-find-the-nearest-lat-long-pair-from-a-list-of-lat-long-in-c-sh) that is close but returns the nearest lat/long entry rather than a list. Also, I don't understand the distance unit used to be able to convert to Miles.

In short, I need a method where...

1. You provide a current Lat/Long pair and a list of Lat/Long pairs
2. Return a sorted list of Lat/Long pairs with distance in Miles

```cs
class Location
{
   double Lat { get; set; }
   double Long { get; set; }
   double Distance { get; set; }
}

public List<Location> SortLocations(Location current, List<Location> locations)
{
   // ???
}
```

Comment: can you tell about lat , long pair, that do you want to get distance between two lat long or between one lat and long?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may be able to use `GeoCoordinate` as mentioned here: [Calculating the distance between 2 points in c#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22686161/calculating-the-distance-between-2-points-in-c-sharp)

Once you can calculate the distance, then you can do something like:

```c#
public List<Location> SortLocations(Location current, List<Location> locations)
{
    foreach (var location in locations)
    {
        location.Distance = CalculateDistance(current, location);
    }
    // Return the list sorted by distance
    return locations.OrderBy(loc => loc.Distance);
}
```

If you don't want to set the `Distance` property on the `locations` collection, you can use `Select`:

```c#
return locationsWithDistance = locations.Select(
    location => new Location
    {
        Lat = location.Lat,
        Long = location.Long,
        Distance = CalculateDistance(current, location)
    }).OrderBy(location => location.Distance);
```

Comment: This is perfect thanks! I had never heard of GeoCoordinate, its great as it simplifies code and returns distance in meters (easy conversion to miles). Then sorting list by distance is perfect, I overlooked that now obvious approach (distance first, then sort distance). I got this all implemented in my code and works great.